ResourceWarning: unclosed running multiprocessing pool: KaggleAPI
class ExtractData:
def __init__(self):
    self.kaggle_api = KaggleApi()
    self.script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    self.data_dir = os.path.join(self.script_dir,'..','data')
    self.download_dir = os.path.abspath(self.data_dir)
    os.environ['KAGGLE_CONFIG_DIR'] = os.path.join(self.script_dir,".kaggle")

    
# This will call kaggle api, perform authentication and download data in Data directory
def download_dataset(self,dataset_name):
    self.kaggle_api.authenticate()
    self.kaggle_api.dataset_download_files(dataset_name, path=self.download_dir, unzip=True)

./opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.19/x64/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/pool.py:265: ResourceWarning: unclosed running multiprocessing pool <multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool state=RUN pool_size=4>
_warn(f"unclosed running multiprocessing pool {self!r}",
ResourceWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
Running this code using Github Action workflow for my project but I am keep on getting this exception, I tried few things but not all. KaggleAPI doesn't have explicit function to close api call after use

quickly browsing the code so maybe wrong but; KaggleApi.authenticate calls _load_config, which creates self.api_client = ApiClient(configuration). ApiClient.__init__ calls self.pool = ThreadPool(). You should therefore be able to call self.kaggle_api.api_client.pool.close().
